# How do I echo $VARIABLE if it is set, or 'default text' if not?

Tags: linux, bash

assuming `$USER_NAME` is a variable, how do I run the following pseduo-code:

```
$ adduser ($USERNAME OR 'defaultUser')
```

The javascript equivalent of setting a variable like this would be:

```
const user = process.env.USERNAME || 'defaultUser'
```

or in Ruby

```
user = ENV['USERNAME'] || 'defaultUser'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
adduser ${USERNAME:-'defaultUser'}
```

Note that the default value will be expanded by `bash`, hence the quotes.

Comment: Note that `:-` will use the default value if the variable is unset *or* null (i.e. a zero-length string). You can also just use `-`, which will only use the default value if the variable is unset. There's also `:=` and `=`, which assign the default value to the variable if it's unset (and for `:=` if it's null as well). See [the Bash Hackers Wiki](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#use_a_default_value) for more info.